# SSL: make Java check the whole trust chain

Tags: java, ssl, https

Say I'm communicating with a client via https with this certificate chain:

```
acme root
  |
  +--- acme intermediate
         |
         +--- server cert
```

I've created a trust store where I've imported the `acme intermediate` certificate using

```
keytool -import -alias intermediate-ca -file acme_intermediate.der -keystore /path/to/intermediate-cacerts
```

and started the VM with ...

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/intermediate-cacerts ...
```

When connecting to the server, the connection is successfully made. I've expected an `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` with `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` or similar because the `acme root` certificate is not stored in my `intermediate-ca`.

To be sure, I've checked if the JVM examined the default system truststore by `strace`ing the JVM but it did not:

```
$ strace -tt -f -etrace=open java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/intermediate-cacerts Program 2>&1 | grep -vE 'open\((.*\.(so|jar)|"/(proc|dev|etc/host|tmp|sys))'

22:31:21.103201 open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg", O_RDONLY) = 3
[pid 27619] 22:31:21.119299 open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/lib/endorsed", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 27619] 22:31:21.125422 open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY) = 3
[pid 27619] 22:31:21.127423 open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 27619] 22:31:21.141141 open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/lib/meta-index", O_RDONLY) = 3
[pid 27619] 22:31:21.540826 open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 4
[pid 27619] 22:31:21.541576 open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
[pid 27619] 22:31:21.542221 open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY) = 4
[pid 27619] 22:31:22.267438 open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/lib/ext/meta-index", O_RDONLY) = 4
[pid 27619] 22:31:22.318007 open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/lib/ext", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
[pid 27619] 22:31:22.462944 open("/usr/java/packages/lib/ext", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 27619] 22:31:22.604155 open("/home/me/Program.class", O_RDONLY) = 4
[pid 27619] 22:31:22.728273 open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/lib/security/java.security", O_RDONLY) = 4
[pid 27619] 22:31:24.048924 open("/usr/share/jbossas/standalone/data/intermediate-cacerts", O_RDONLY) = 9
[pid 27619] 22:31:24.462164 open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/lib/meta-index", O_RDONLY) = 10
[pid 27619] 22:31:24.626192 open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY) = 11
[pid 27619] 22:31:25.523615 open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/lib/net.properties", O_RDONLY) = 12
[pid 27619] 22:31:26.168961 --- SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) @ 0 (0) ---
Successfully connected
```

When omitting the `-Djavax.net.ssl` options I observe `open()` of the system truststore:

```
[pid 27212] 10:54:53.699479 open("/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-oracle-1.7.0.51.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts", O_RDONLY) = 9
```

The connection is created using this code fragment:

```
SSLSocketFactory sslsocketfactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) sslsocketfactory.createSocket(hostname, port);
```

This and serveral resources on the internet say that there's no way to make Java lookup certificates in multiple truststores. They say one need to clone the system truststore and import needed extra certificates. Sounds plausible to me.

- Are there configuration options to make Java check the whole trust chain?
- If not, what should I implement manually to check the trust chain?

Comment: As long as any of the certificates in the chain presented are trusted, the handshake will succeed. You didn't need to import the entire chain, only the top element of it.